# Why embarassingly parallel jobs go much slower on a server based on slurm than locally when using R?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, slurm

I run the following `R` script both on my personal computer and a computing facility based on `slurm` queuing system

```
foo = 
  function(size){
    sample = rnorm(size)
    mean = mean(sample)
    sd = sd(sample)
    vOut = c("mean" = mean, "sd" = sd)
    return(vOut)
  }

# nonparallel case
begin = Sys.time()
for(i in rep(1e7, 80)){
  foo(i)
}
end = Sys.time()
print("nopar")
print(end - begin)

# parallel case
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cores = 16
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1], outfile = "") 
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = ncor)
begin = Sys.time()
foreach(x = rep(1e7, 80)) %dopar% {
  foo(x)
}
end = Sys.time()
print("Par")
print(end - begin)
```

To launch it on the server I use the following batch file named `execute`

```
#!/bin/bash
#sbatch - -ntasks=16
#sbatch --cpus-per-task=1
#sbatch - -output=/scratch/user/out.txt

Rscript --vanilla Programs/Valid4_parallel_norm.R
```

which I call from the console via

```
sbatch ./execute
```

Running it on my own computer it takes 45 seconds on a single core and 6 seconds on multiple (16 cores).
Whereas when running it on the server it takes in both cases around 1 minute.

What could it be the reason? Could it be an issue with the server?
It also does not seem to me that the program requires much memory to be allocated and transferred across cores.

Comment: Probably a combination of cheap computational workload and data copying overhead. Slurm (and similar solutions) also have a fairly large initial overhead and only really make sense for much larger job sizes.

Comment: It does not really happen. If I change 1e7 to 1e8 I get in both cases around 9 minutes on the server whereas I get 1.5 minutes on multiple cores of my pc

Comment: Even `foo(1e8)` runs pretty fast on my computer (~ 3s). This is probably still way too fast to benefit from cross-machine parallelism, especially via a complex workload scheduler such as Slurm. I don’t have Slurm available but just submitting and executing a trivial job (e.g. `Rscript -e 1`) will probably take over a second.

Comment: You should test with something well-defined such as `Sys.sleep(20)`. Then you'll know exactly how much time is invested for overhead.

Comment: Using `Sys.sleep(2)` works fine. When it is repeated as many times as the number of cores, it just takes slightly above 2 seconds to execute all of them in parallel against # cores * 2 when not parallelized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

First, to see the number of CPU cores your current job script gets, add the following before calling `Rscript ...`:

```
command -v nproc > /dev/null && echo "Number of CPU cores: $(nproc)"
```

This will tell you how many CPU cores Slurm gives your job.  Then add the following to the top of your R script:

```
message("Number of CPU cores in R: ", parallelly::availableCores())
```

This will show the same from within R.

I suspect you get either 1 or 2.  Can you please report back what you get when you add those two lines to your current scripts?

Second, Slurm declarations should be in upper case, i.e. `#SLURM ...`.  Slurm doesn't recognize lower-case `#sbatch ...`.  Because of this, your job script gets the default number of CPU cores, which is why I think you get 1 or 2 above.

Third, the Slurm cluster you run on is probably configured with something called Linux Control Groups, short CGroups. This prevents a job script from using more CPU cores than it is given.  If my suspicion is correct, where your job script only gets 1 or 2 CPU cores, then, when you create a cluster of 16 parallel workers, those workers compete for this single CPU core, or possible two.  That slows things down tremendously - as it should, because otherwise your job would steal CPU time from other jobs running on the same machine.

Fourth, do *not* specify `--cpus-per-task=1` - that will cause your R script to get only a single CPU core.  (In your case, it never had an effect, because you used lower-case Slurm declarations)

Fifth, make sure to no introduce spurious spaces in your Slurm options, specifically `- -ntasks=16` is not a valid option. It should be `--ntasks=16`.  Same for `--output=...`

---

So, instead, do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1     ## make sure to parallelize on a single machine
#SBATCH --ntasks=16

Rscript --vanilla Programs/Valid4_parallel_norm.R
```

and then

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

## Get the number of CPU cores that the system allows
ncores <- parallelly::availableCores()
message("Number of CPU cores in R: ", ncores)

## Create 'ncores' parallel workers
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores)

## Tell %dopar% to use these parallel workers
registerDoParallel(cl)

foo <- function(size) {
    sample <- rnorm(size)
    mean <- mean(sample)
    sd <- sd(sample)
    vOut <- c("mean" = mean, "sd" = sd)
    return(vOut)
}

begin <- Sys.time()
res <- foreach(x = rep(1e7, 80)) %dopar% {
  foo(x)
}
end <- Sys.time()
print(end - begin)
```

More comments about your code:

You used `registerDoParallel(cl, cores = ncor)`. `ncor` is never defined in your script.  The correct way is to use either `registerDoParallel(cl)` or `registerDoParallel(cores = ncores)` - I recommend the former.

I've seen `makeCluster(cores[1])` used by quite a few people. It's sufficient to do `makeCluster(cores)`. I'm not sure where the `[1]` subsetting originates from, but I suspect it's in some online instructions out there that users keep finding. Where did you learn to use `cores[1]` from?  It would be nice to tell whoever wrote that documentation to remove that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the issue was my lowercase typing with which I only got a single core (despite higher availability), which was presumably the object of competition by the workers within the cluster. The notation `cores[1]` was just taken by some example about how using the command on the web